# Is it possible to launch a hyperlink within the email body from a specific sender?

Tags: vbscript

Goal: My goal is to have OUTLOOK filter an incoming message based on keywords (which can be done with rules) but, I need to run a script that will automatically open the link within the email.

Configuration: Our back-end system has a button that says "Need Attention" this sends an email as follows Outlook 2013 Want to open in current page (chrome) as a new tab or in new window as long as it opens

LINKS HAVE BEEN CHANGED FOR SECURITY

" HTTP: " removed per posting requirements

SUBJECT: (always containing the same words except for the customer number)

Attn - Need Support for: LOC-12345 / Rep ID: mike / Tech: jacob / Status: new requests / Service: Standard Service

BODY (always containing the same words except for the customer number in both the body and hyperlink)

Attn - Need Support for: LOC-12345(customer number)

To view account, click the link below: //support.bo.ca/login.aspx?url=view_rfq.aspx?rfq_ID=12345

Summary: May seem like I'm just lazy and don't want to click a link. But the situation is that we have over 20 actions with 20 different email subjects, I have code for setting reminders and moving to particular folders but this would be great, because as soon as an account representative clicks the "Need Attention" button it will send an email to the assigned support group and pop up on their screen. We have this already in place with our phone system by recognizing the caller id and matching our database for that number if there's a hit it will auto open the customers page.

This is the code I've found but I don't understand how to make it work also I the thought of having maybe a code that will automatically generate a partial hyperlink, pull the customer ID and input it into the partial hyperlink and open the page? For example using the SplitWord entry to replace certain amount of characters from the beginning with the partial link and execute it?

(partial link) //support.bo.ca/login.aspx?url=view_rfq.aspx? rfq_ID= (customer ID) 12345 (complete link) //support.bo.ca/login.aspx?url=view_rfq.aspx? rfq_ID=12345

```
    Private WithEvents myOlItems  As Outlook.Items
```

Private Sub Application_Startup()
        Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
        Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
          Set olApp = Outlook.Application
          Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
          Set myOlItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

```
  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item

    LaunchURL (item)
   For Each SplitLine In bodyStringSplitLine
        If InStr(SplitLine, "http://") > 0 Then

           If InStr(SplitLine, "SomeSite") > 0 Then
            bodyStringSplitWord = Split(SplitLine, " ")
            For Each SplitWord In bodyStringSplitWord
            If Left(SplitWord, 7) = "http://" Then
            Shell ("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" & " " & SplitWord)
       End If
       Next
       End If

    End If
Next
    End If

    ProgramExit:
    Exit Sub
    ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
    End Sub
```

Thank you for any feedback
Jacob